# Rename files numerically in place, multiple folders

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am able to rename files numerically, in place, in multiple folders. However, it is not the result I am looking for. My file structure looks as follows:

```
Pictures-
    Vacation-
        img.001.jpg                                                    
        img.002.jpg                                                   
        img.003.jpg                                                    
    Holidays-
        img.004.jpg
        img.005.jpg                                                    
        img.006.jpg                                                   
    Fun-
        img.007.jpg
```

What I'd like to achieve is:

```
Pictures-                                                                   
    Vacation-
        img.001.jpg
        img.002.jpg
        img.003.jpg
    Holidays-
        img.001.jpg
        img.002.jpg
        img.003.jpg
    Fun-
        img.001.jpg
```

So far I have come up with the following:

```
a=1
for i in $vm/Holiday/*; do
    new=$(printf "%03d.jpg" ${a})
    mv ${i} $vm/Holiday/${new}
    let a=a+1
done
```

How can I achieve my desired result without having to separately run this on every single directory within my pictures folder?

Comment: Could you post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this with `iphone` but I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your version and make it iterate over the folders as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ~/code/stack/Pictures/*; do
        [ -d "${dir}" ] || continue
        i=1
        for img in "${dir}"/*.jpg; do
                [ -e "${img}" ] || break
                new="$(printf "%03d.jpg" "${i}")"
                echo mv "${img}" "$(dirname "${img}")/${new}"
                ((i++))
        done
done
```

Change the location of your Pictures folder and dryrun with the echo in place first. Is that what you wanted...?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed and is logical enough to understand. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ls > folders        #cat top folders into folders
while read folder   
   do
   cd $folder          #go to vacation folder for   example
   i=0
   ls *.jpg > files
   while read line
       do
       mv $line img.$i.jpg   #rename files according to your need
       i=$(($i+1))
       done < "files"
   rm files
   cd ..
   done < "folders"
rm folders
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function renameImages {
    local i=1;
    for oldFile in * ; do
        if [ -d "$oldFile" ] ; then
            pushd "$oldFile" >/dev/null
            renameImages
            popd >/dev/null
        elif [ "${oldFile##*.}" == "jpg" ] ; then
            newFile=$(printf img.%03d.jpg $i)
            echo "$PWD/$oldFile -> $PWD/$newFile"
            i=$((i+1))
        fi
    done
}

renameImages
```

This won't actually rename any files, but instead it will print on screen how it would.

If you're happy with what it does, change

```
echo "$PWD/$oldFile -> $PWD/$newFile"
```

to

```
mv "$PWD/$oldFile" "$PWD/$newFile"
```

**NOTE:** The first edit of this answer would rename all files, .jpg or not.  This version only renames .jpgs.

Comment: This almost produces the desired result, but results in an endless loop and catches a few other folders.. I'll play with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
for i in $vm/Vacation/*; do
new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${a}) 
mv ${i} $vm/Vacation/${new}
let a=a+1
done

b=1
for i in $vm/Holiday/*; do
new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${b}) 
mv ${i} $vm/Holiday/${new}
let b=b+1
done

c=1
for i in $vm/Fun/*; do
new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${c}) 
mv ${i} $vm/Fun/${new}
let c=c+1
done
```

This is long and tedious, not ideal, but it works. With years of folders to sort and add pictures to as I come across them, a much shorter solution would have been accepted.